# Select all rows that equal on same column (unknown) value

Tags: sql

My table lists threads between x users. Each user can be in y threads.

Below, `user_id` `1` is in thread `1` and `2`, and so on...

Now, lets say `user_id` `1` is given only, how can I get all rows that have the same `thread_id` as the row that has `user_id` `1`?

```
       id   user_id  thread_id
        1     1        1    
        2     1        2    
        3     2        1    
        4     3        2
```

Have no clue...

---

EDIT

Given are the `user_uid`s 1 and 2. Now get me the thread_id that only both of them share. I dont want all threads of 1 and 2 but only the one that they share together.

Comment: Can you clarify the question?  Are you looking for anyone that has 1 or 2, 1 and 2 only, or 1 and 2 and possibly some others?

Comment: Sorry for lack of info. I need to say, I have ALL `user_id`s that are of interest. Now I want to find exactly the `thread_id` that is shared by ALL of the `user_id`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct thread_id from tableX
where thread_id in (select thread_id from tableX where user_id=1)
and thread_id in (select thread_id from tableX where user_id=2)
```

I have modified my answer to fit your comment clarification. Give this a shot.

Comment: Thanks, lets say only user_id 1 and 2 is relevant. How can I select the shared thread_id where only those two are in?

Comment: if you want to user 1 and 2 you can just add an OR to the nested query like: select * from tableX
where thread_id in (select thread_id from tableX where user_id=1 OR user_id=2). This gets all threads that user 1 and 2 are assigned to.

Comment: But this again gives me different thread_ids. My result may only contain 1 thread_id in multtiple rows with different user_ids.

Comment: This gives me an empty result

Comment: I just modified my answer above after reading your clarification comments on your question. I think this is this is what you are asking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find pairs of users that have exactly the same set of threads, then the following query will work:

```
select t.user_id, t2.user_id
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by t.user_id) as NumThreads
      from t
     ) t left outer join
     t t2
     on t.thread_id = t2.thread_id and t.user_id <> t2.user_id
group by t.user_id, t2.user_id
having SUM(case when t.user_id is null then 1 else 0 end) = 0 and
       SUM(case when t2.user_id is null then 1 else 0 end) = 0 and
       count(*) = max(t.NumThreads)
```

In this query, wherever it says "from t t2" you would put "from  t2".  Where the line is "from t" you would put "from  t".

The structure of this query is a self-join with an aggregation.  The intention to to find every pair of matching threads.  Then to group them by the two user_ids.  If the number of matching threads is the number of threads for the user (the third condition) *and* no threads fail to match (the first two conditions), then the two users match on all their threads.

Your question in the comments about threads on all users is easier.

```
select thread_id
from t cross join
     (select count(distinct user_id) as NumUsers from t) const
group by thread_id
having count(*) = max(const.NumUsers)
```

Comment: @Indianer . . . I don't understand your comment at all.  This query only references one table, which is called `t` in the query, because you did not give it a name in the question.

Comment: @Indianer . . . It is an alias for `t`.  Do you know SQL at all?  The structure of this query is a self-join with an aggregation.

Comment: Running your comment answer gives me a empty result... Thanks btw for your help.

Comment: @Indianer . . . That would suggest that no thread is shard by all users.

Comment: Yes its not about all users being in one thread. It is possible that users 1 and 2 are only in thread 1 however user 3 not. I want all users (2 up to x) that share exactly the same thread_id

Comment: Gordon how do I use your first example with the alias, lets say my table is called "table_123"?

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @id int
set @id = (select thread_id from threads where user_id = 1)

select * from threads where thread_id = @id
```

Comment: Hmmm, the second line of this query will fail, because there are two thread_ids for user 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE user_id!=1 AND
      thread_id IN (SELECT thread_id FROM table WHERE user_id=1);
```

New answer based on Indianer's edited description of question:

```
SELECT * FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 ON t1.thread_id=t2.thread_id AND t1.user_id!=t2.user_id
WHERE t1.user_id IN (1,2) AND t2.user_id IN (1,2);
```

Comment: I've edited my answer, since your first post seemed like you wanted all the other rows that had the same thread_ids used by user_id=1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EXISTS`:

```
DECLARE @userID INT 
SET @userID = 1 

SELECT u1.id, u1.user_id, u1.thread_id 
FROM   userthreads u1 
WHERE  u1.userid <> @userId 
       AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                  FROM   userthreads u2 
                  WHERE  u2.userid <> u1.userid 
                         AND u2.threadid = u1.threadid)
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d5270/3/0)

If you want to include the user with the given userID omit the `WHERE  u2.userid <> u1.userid`.

Comment: This will return multiple thread_ids for the users. Please see my edit.